Where did I send my litecoin when sending it to this wallet: MJppB2TYmisQRuZe1nA2QKNqhvsKJ2xqMR
I thought I was sending my litecoin to a Coinbase address using BitPay. The transaction was complete but never received my funds. The wall address I sent it to is:
MJppB2TYmisQRuZe1nA2QKNqhvsKJ2xqMR
Where did I send my litecoin?

Have you tried contacting the Coinbase support team? We don’t have insight into Coinbase’s address database, so there is no way for us to tell you what happened to you payment to Coinbase.
